# Implementing Tabs and Data grid together in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a problem in my project.I want to implement Tab bar function under a drop down selection and when once tab bar is clicked it has to be navigated to a data grid.Can any body suggest me the proper direction to implement it.

Thanks,
Brenda

Comment: Not sure I'm following you correctly, what does the drop down have to do with the tab and datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Use a tab navigator, add canvases as children to that navigator, put your datagrid on one of those children.